# How to run Android application on Bluestack app player using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm using Eclipse to develop Android application, now I want to use Bluestack as my emulator. I tried

> adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555

successfully and I could find Bluestack in my device list when running the app. In the Console windows says

> Starting activity example.com.SplashActivity on device 127.0.0.1:5555

and my Devices view lies my app.
I even installed Launcher Pro on Bluestack, however I can't see my app showing in Bluestack. How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see your app in app list?

Comment: My app doesn't appear in app list in Bluestack, but I open Devices view in Eclipse and I do see my app running on Bluestack device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i know you need to install apk file in Bluestack app player after that you can run your app on bluestack.If you have installed bluestack then double click on apk file,it will be automatically installed in bluestack app player.

Comment: I installed 1 apk file and now I can deploy my app using Eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried:
adb connect 127.0.0.1
then, create simple project in Eclipse, then "run configuration" - "target" - "Always prompt to pick device" - "Run". End project automatically run in Bluestack simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Change your google account password that is related with bluestacks. 
The updates can not proceed without the password confirmation. 
Never update the password in bluestacks. 
There would be no more automatic app installation.